# What kind of UITableView is used by iPad Reminders?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, layout

What kind of `UITableView` `UITableViewStylePlain` or `UITableViewStyleGrouped` is used by iPad Reminders on the left side? How could I create exact the same layout?
What kind of separator line is used?

Comment: Why the downvotes / close? This seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: Yeah, it's nothing more than a really broad set of questions... I don't see how "this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as if they're using `UITableViewSTylePlain` and hosting the `UITableView` inside their own controller that lays it out with rounded corners, the search thingy, the dark colors, etc.  They're rendering a custom separator line.  You will basically have to do custom everything to implement a view that looks exactly the same.  You'll have to have your own custom `UITableViewCell` as well, with a custom check-mark accessory view.

Comment: Do you have experience customizing separator line?

Comment: My only problem is, that it is a plain  uitableview, but it uses an etch separator line, that is just available for grouped tableview. Strange.

Comment: You can draw whatever kind of separator you want in your UITableViewCell.